# SwiftUI Text in between Images is not aligned properly

Tags: swiftui, vstack

Having a simple `SwiftUI` view:

```
VStack {
    Image("AnIcon")
    Text("AAA").font(.system(size: 100))
    Image("AnIcon")
}
```

the spacings above and below the `Text` differ.

If I replace the two images by `Text`, The texts are directly adjacent to each other (e.g. the blue lines overlap).

What is the reason for having different spacing above and below?

Also, why there is even so much space? I would assume the `Image` and `Text` shall have no extra spacing in between, the same way as when three texts are.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just use `VStack(spacing: 0)`

Comment: Now I've figured that `VStack(spacing: 0)` removes the extra spacing. However, I still do not understand why the default spacing is not distributed evenly, and how is the default spacing calculated.